# Find value of the last NOT NULL column in each row of a table in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table in my database where I store addresses. The address can be many lines (1 to 6)

Each line of the address is stored as a separate column, up to 6 columns.

I now want to loop through each row in my table and find the value of the last NOT NULL column. This could be column 3,4,5 or 6.

I need a SQL command where given a row I get the value of the last column which is not null.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the documentation for COALESCE? Why do you think you need a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a little on what you mean by last not-null column.  I'm assuming you mean 'given this list, return the first one with a value', where the list is [6, 5, 4, 3].  If so, use this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(col6, col5, col4, col3)
FROM AddressTable
WHERE rowId = :input
```

The `COALESCE()` function returns the first value that resolves to not null, or null if all values are null.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [`COALESCE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) which returns the first non-null value:

```
SELECT    COALESCE(Address6, Address5, Address4, Address3) AS LastNonNullValue
FROM      YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) command:

```
SELECT COALESCE(column6, column5, column4, column3) FROM tbl
```

Note the reverse order of the columns to select the first non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would give you the column number:

```
select 
    left(coalesce('0'+address6, '6'+address5, '5'+address4, '4'+address3, '3'+address2, '2'+address1, '1'),1)
from @Address
```